# Why is one of my <hr /> tags much smaller than the others?

Tags: php, html, css

Why isn't the HR line doing what the rest of the lines are?

[image: x]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/d24c737e4f3bfb777843b4e2c88c1a7b.png))</sub>

It's a bit hard to see but the first one is not in proportion to the rest, it's smaller than the others.. I am unsure why?

My CSS.

```
hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Where my hr is:

```
echo "<h1><hr />" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</h1>";
```

CODE:

```
<?php 
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
session_start();
//checks if the login session is true

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---


 include ('header.php'); 



        ?>




    <div class="blog-wrap">


        <section class="blog-content">



            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style1.css">

            <form action="search.php" class="searchbar1" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-search" value="Search" />
    </form>



<div style="float:right">  <a class="btn btn-danger logout" href="logout.php" > Logout</a> </div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="home.php" target="_self" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Sessions</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Session 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="session2.php" target="_self" >Session 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="session3.php" target="_self" >Session 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="session4.php" target="_self" >Session 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="session5.php" target="_self" >Session 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="session6.php" target="_self" >Session 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="session7.php" target="_self" >Session 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="session8.php" target="_self" >Session 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="session9.php" target="_self" >Session 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="session10.php" target="_self" >Session 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="session11.php" target="_self" >Session 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="session12.php" target="_self" >Session 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="session13.php" target="_self" >Session 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="session14.php" target="_self" >Session 14</a></li>



            </ul>
            <li><a href="blog.php" target="_self" >Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.php" target="_self" >Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
<?php 
                include "blogsidebar.php";
            ?>
            </div>
            <section class="blog-inner">
                <div class="blog-posts">
                    <?php 
                        $sql = "SELECT blog.*, users.*, category.*, COUNT(comment.blogID) AS commentcount 
                        FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON blog.authorID = users.userID INNER JOIN category ON 
                        blog.catID = category.catID LEFT JOIN comment ON blog.blogID = comment.blogID GROUP BY 
                        blog.blogID, comment.blogID ORDER BY dateposted DESC LIMIT 0,3"; //display the last 3 blog entries and count the number of comments for each blog entry 

                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection)); //run the query 

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                        echo "<article class='blog-post one'>";
                        echo "<aside class='blog-text-prev'>";
                        echo "<div class='text-content'>";
                        echo "<h1><hr />" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</h1>";
                        echo "<h1>" . $row['categoryImage'] .  "  " . $row['fullname'] . "  ". $row['category'] ."  " . date("F jS",strtotime($row['dateTime'])) . " </h1>";
                        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
                        echo "<p>" . (substr(($row['blogContent']),0,304)) . " <i><b><a href='blog-post.php?blogID=" .$row['blogID']. "'>Read More...</a></i></b></p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</aside>";
                        echo "</article>";
                        }
                    ?>

                </div>

            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end login -->
<?php 
    include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: ...its hard to diagnose an issue with code from only an image of the code's output. Can you provide a live example at all?

Comment: @SW4 I can't as it's using PHP it will give you errors.

Comment: while seeing `HR` my first thought was `Human Resource`  .. you need to improve it

Comment: @Sally your concern is `border-bottom` not appearing? right? If yes ` border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;` which is white so bottom border not shows.

Comment: Please make a reduced test case in something like codepen or jsfiddle, taking out the PHP and using plain HTML instead.

Comment: Just copy the page generated source and paste it in the question. We don't really need the PHP bits to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @KheemaPandey My concern is the first <hr> is shorter than the others?

Comment: you using `float:right` for `Logout` button have you cleared it?.. we can only guess here

Comment: @KheemaPandey Yeah I have used float right nothing :(

Comment: can you post a rendered HTML code

Comment: ...or make a fiddle/codepen. And is the parent `<h1 />` just as wide as the other ones?

Comment: @Sally : paste the CSS of `<h1>` which encloses `<hr>` in question..

Comment: I think the problem lies within the size of the containig `<h1>` node, or some similar container. Could you post the CSS for that too?

Comment: @pqnet The issue was my sidebar it is relative but when I change it to absolute it fixes it, but in different resolutions it goes inside the text. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sally post the CSS code you are using for your sidebar. Is it `floating: right;`? This will make everything on its left shrink

Comment: @Sally then use `position:relative` for parent element and for sidebar use `right:0;`  with `position:absolute`

Comment: @KheemaPandey Yeah still the top line is shorter than the rest :(

Comment: also, do you really need to put `<hr>` inside an `<h1>` tag? It looks a bit weird to me

Comment: @KheemaPandey I've fixed it but the sidebar floats to the right extremely

Comment: Try `echo "<hr /><h1>" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</h1>";` - If `<hr/>` is inside `<h1>` tags (*which shouldn't be in the first place*), it will take on those properties, and any other CSS related to `<h1>`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hr is now moved way up top.. http://gyazo.com/67e64050c5856cf322a500c6ee3f1e0f

Comment: Then try removing the `<hr/>` from it, and doing `echo "<hr/>";` and placing it just above `echo "<article class='blog-post one'>";`

Answer (score 0):

You placed the `<hr>` in a `<h1>` node, that won't work.

And check this here, in HTML5 it's just for semantics
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_hr.asp

> "However, the `<hr>` tag may still be displayed as a horizontal rule in visual browsers, 
>    but is now defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms."

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't put the hr inside your h1. I would simply set the h1 tag to have a top border.